# last item in the listview inside view pager does not appear correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

in my android application
i used list view inside ViewPager but the last item does not appear as a full item, the scroll befor the last item appear as shown in the screenshot

[image: screenshot of the problem]

message_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:elevation="1.4dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_icon"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/inbox_photo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="Message icon"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sender_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/message_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sender_label"
        android:textColor="@color/seconderyTexy"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="sample"
        />
 </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

inbox_fragment.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">
            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false">
            </ListView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/empty_inbox" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.fadi.fadiqua.follow.MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_alt_black_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You can hide navigationbar.

Comment: Try Changing your layout to LinearLayout(from Relativelayout) and add android:fitsSystemWindows attribute to it.You can also try setting android:marginBottom="?attr/actionbarSize"

Comment: thanx, i sloved it by changing coordinate to linear